# Como calcular a idade baseando na DATA de nascimento no MySQL baseado no mês e dia?

Tags: mysql

Tenho a consulta abaixo, mas ela ignora o mês e dia de nascimento

```
SELECT
    FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(), c.nascimento) / 365) AS idade
FROM
    clientes c
```

No resultado, a maior parte vem certo, mas às vezes tem tem diferença de um ano. Como fazer a consulta, mas levando em conta o mês e dia de nascimento?

Comment: Você precisa levar em conta também os anos que são bissextos.

Comment: Como poderia calcular usando o ano bissexto?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Existem várias possibilidades. A sua funciona, mas como nem todo ano tem 365 dias, ela nunca será precisa.

Uma possibilidade:

```
SELECT
    YEAR(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(c.nascimento))) AS idade
FROM
    clientes
```

Poderia ser assim também:

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, c.nascimento, NOW()) AS idade
```

Ou esta bem feia:

```
SUBSTRING(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(c.nascimento)), 3, 2) AS idade
```

Sucesso!

Answer (score 5):

Esta função obtém o numero exato de anos completos com base na data de aniversário:

```
SELECT YEAR(dHoje)-YEAR(dNasc)-IIF(MONTH(dHoje)*32+DAY(dHoje)<MONTH(dNasc)*32+DAY(dNasc),1,0)
```

Notar que ela não se baseia em aproximações e cálculos, mas sim considera o dia atual para determinar se o aniversário da data de hoje (ou de referência) ainda não chegou.

Mantive com a variável em vez da data corrente para ficar fácil calcular a idade a partir de outras referências.

> Caso prefira substituir o dHoje, use CURRENT_DATE ou CURDATE() no lugar de NOW()

Answer (score 4):

A melhor e mais refinada alternativa é esta:

```
SELECT 
   TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, c.nascimento, CURDATE()) as idade 
FROM
   clientes c
```

Esta função é ótima.

Answer (score 1):

**1º Forma**

```
SELECT
   YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) - YEAR(c.nascimento) - (DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(c.nascimento, '%m%d')) as idade
FROM
   clientes c
```

**2º Forma**

```
SELECT    
   TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, c.nascimento, CURRENT_DATE) as idade 
FROM
   clientes c
```

**3º Forma**

```
SELECT    
   YEAR(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE,c.nascimento)))  as idade 
FROM
   clientes c
```

Answer (score 0):

**Também tem essa forma:**

DATE_FORMAT(coluna_nascimento, '%d/%m/%Y') AS Nascimento, TRUNCATE(DATEDIFF(NOW(), coluna_nascimento)/365.25, 0) AS Idade

**O 365.25 é para compensar o ano bissexto**

Answer (score 0):

Decidi fazer alguns testes com algumas fórmulas sugeridas por outros nesse post.
As fórmulas que peguei para olhar foram:

1. `TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, data_nasc, data_atual)`
2. `YEAR(data_atual) - YEAR(data_nasc) - (DATE_FORMAT(data_atual, '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(data_nasc, '%m%d'))`
3. `FLOOR(DATEDIFF(data_atual, data_nasc) / 365.25)`
4. `YEAR(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(data_atual)-TO_DAYS(data_nasc)))`

A partir disso fiz o seguinte script para testá-las em alguns cenários com ano bissexto e datas de aniversário:

```
drop database if exists testeFormulaIdade;
create database testeFormulaIdade;
use testeFormulaIdade;

create table datas_de_teste (
    id int not null primary key auto_increment,
    data_nasc date,
    data_atual date,
    formula_01 int,
    formula_02 int,
    formula_03 int,
    formula_04 int
);

-- ANO NORMAL COM ANO NORMAL
insert into datas_de_teste values (default,"1999-01-15","2023-01-10",0,0,0,0);
insert into datas_de_teste values (default,"1999-01-15","2023-01-20",0,0,0,0);

-- ANO BISSEXTO COM ANO NORMAL
insert into datas_de_teste values (default,"2000-02-29","2023-01-10",0,0,0,0);
insert into datas_de_teste values (default,"2000-02-29","2023-03-10",0,0,0,0);

-- ANO NORMAL COM ANO BISSEXTO 
insert into datas_de_teste values (default,"1999-03-15","2020-02-29",0,0,0,0);
insert into datas_de_teste values (default,"1999-01-15","2020-02-29",0,0,0,0);

-- ANO BISSEXTO COM ANO BISSEXTO
insert into datas_de_teste values (default,"2000-02-29","2020-01-15",0,0,0,0);
insert into datas_de_teste values (default,"2000-02-29","2020-03-15",0,0,0,0);
insert into datas_de_teste values (default,"2000-03-28","2021-03-28",0,0,0,0);

-- DATAS DIVERSAS NO DIA DO ANIVERSÁRIO
insert into datas_de_teste values (default,"2001-02-02","2003-02-02",0,0,0,0);
insert into datas_de_teste values (default,"2001-02-02","2007-02-02",0,0,0,0);
insert into datas_de_teste values (default,"2001-02-02","2009-02-02",0,0,0,0);
insert into datas_de_teste values (default,"2000-02-02","2005-02-02",0,0,0,0);

update datas_de_teste 
set formula_01 =  TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, data_nasc, data_atual) 
where id != 0;      

update datas_de_teste 
set formula_02 = YEAR(data_atual) - YEAR(data_nasc) - (DATE_FORMAT(data_atual, '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(data_nasc, '%m%d')) 
where id != 0;

update datas_de_teste 
set formula_03 = FLOOR(DATEDIFF(data_atual, data_nasc) / 365.25) -- OU 365.242199076 CONFORME PREFERIR
where id != 0;              
-- CUIDADO SE USAR 365 SEM CASAS DECIMAIS HAVERÁ IMPRESISSÃO COM AS DATAS "1999-01-15","2023-01-10"

update datas_de_teste 
set formula_04 = YEAR(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(data_atual)-TO_DAYS(data_nasc))) 
where id != 0;      

select * from datas_de_teste;
```

Com esse script obtive a seguinte tabela:

[resposta da query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EANeR.png)

Podemos ver nas linhas de id 11 e 12 da imagem que as fórmulas

- `FLOOR(DATEDIFF(data_atual, data_nasc) / 365.25)`
- `YEAR(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(data_atual)-TO_DAYS(data_nasc)))`

mostram uma mudança de comportamento inesperado ao passarem a incrementar a idade não no dia após o aniversário, mas no dia do aniversário dependendo de qual é o intervalo das datas inseridas.

Logo as fórmulas abaixo se mostram mais interessantes quando o requisito é que o momento de atualização da idade se mantenha o mesmo:

- `TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, data_nasc, data_atual)`
- `YEAR(data_atual) - YEAR(data_nasc) - (DATE_FORMAT(data_atual, '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(data_nasc, '%m%d'))`

Obs: Fiz isso também com outras fórmulas e até fiz a minha, mas as que mostrei exemplificam bem as soluções que encontrei até o momento. Posso estar errado em algo nesse caso ao ser informado corrigirei ou apagarei essa resposta.