# Definir idade a partir da data de nascimento em outra tabela

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Estou tentando criar uma *trigger* para definir o atributo idade da tabela `funcionario`:

````
```sql

   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `funcionario`(
      `cpf_funcionario` INT(11) NOT NULL,      
      `idade` SMALLINT(10) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY(`cpf_funcionario`),  
      FOREIGN KEY (`cpf_funcionario`)
      REFERENCES `pessoa` (`cpf`)
      ON UPDATE CASCADE
      ON DELETE RESTRICT)
    ENGINE = InnoDB;
```
````

A idade seria pega da tabela pessoa:

````
   ```sql  
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pessoa` (
      `cpf` INT(11) NOT NULL,      
      `nome` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
      `data_Nascimento` DATE NOT NULL,      
      `cep` VARCHAR(9) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `telefone` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`cpf`))
    ENGINE = InnoDB;

    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER CalcIdade
    AFTER INSERT ON funcionario
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      set NEW.idade = (YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(NEW.data_Nascimento) - (RIGHT(CURDATE(),5)) < RIGHT(NEW.data_Nascimento,5)) AS idade FROM pessoa);
    END$$
    
    DELIMITER $$
```
````

Mas não tive êxito.

EDIT:

````
 ``` sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE VIEW IdadeFuncionarios AS
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, P.`data_Nascimento`, NOW()) 
FROM funcionario F, pessoa P
INNER JOIN `pessoa`
ON (F.`cpf_funcionario` = P.`cpf`);

DELIMITER $$
```
````

Não funcionou também ou fiz algo de errado?

Comment: Não faz sentido gravar "idade" no banco de dados , grave a data de nascimento e a calcule.  Se é a idade em uma determinada data e só tratar (no lugar do 'now')  pode-se ainda usar uma coluna calculada para isto   https://devtools.com.br/blog/como-calcular-a-idade-no-mysql/    http://www.bosontreinamentos.com.br/mysql/criando-e-usando-colunas-geradas-campos-calculados-em-tabelas-no-mysql/

Comment: Concordo que não faz sentido, mas a aplicação precisa gravar "idade". Estou com dificuldade de achar material que me ajude nesse sentido. Se fosse na mesma tabela com esse trigger já conseguiria resolver

Comment: Poderia fazer uma visão com o campo calculado. Criar uma `view`. Resolveria?

Comment: E como seria essa view? Posso ver de fazer uma workaround rs

Comment: aqui tem outra pergunta que mostra como calcular: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10403/como-calcular-a-idade-baseando-na-data-de-nascimento-no-mysql-baseado-no-m%c3%aas-e-d , basta por isso numa view como sugeriu o @ClarckMaciel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> CREATE VIEW IdadeFuncionarios AS
>   SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, P.`data_Nascimento`, NOW()) 
>     FROM funcionario F, pessoa P
>    INNER JOIN `pessoa` ON (F.`cpf_funcionario` = P.`cpf`);
> ```

O Problema aqui está na junção, devendo retirar o trecho `, pessoa P`, então sua `view` ficaria assim:

```
CREATE VIEW IdadeFuncionarios AS
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, P.`data_Nascimento`, NOW()) 
  FROM funcionario F
 INNER JOIN `pessoa` ON (F.`cpf_funcionario` = P.`cpf`);
```

Porém essa `view` estaria apenas retornando o campo idade sem informar a qual  pessoa pertence.

Fiz um exemplo com base nas suas tabelas com uma pequena adaptação em `funcionarios` retirando o campo `idade` em conformidade com o comentário do @Motta que afirmou que *'Não faz sentido gravar "idade" no banco de dados , grave a data de nascimento e a calcule.'*, desta forma **a idade será calculada na `view`**.
Acrescentei o campo `salario` para exemplificar a situação em que a visão dos dados das tabelas deva retornar: **Nome, Salário, Idade**.
Exemplo está disponibilizado em: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c6e9b/1)

Pra essa solução, [conforme exemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c6e9b/1), poderia utilizar a seguinte view:

```
CREATE VIEW FuncionarioSalarioIdade AS
   SELECT P.nome, F.salario, P.`data_Nascimento`, 
          Cast(NOW() as date) as Hoje, 
          TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, P.`data_Nascimento`, NOW()) as idade
     FROM funcionario F 
    INNER JOIN `pessoa` P ON (F.`cpf_funcionario` = P.`cpf`);
```

[Segue o código completo do exemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c6e9b/1):

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table pessoa
(
    cpf int not null
        primary key,
    nome varchar(100) not null,
    data_Nascimento date not null,
    cep varchar(9) null,
    telefone varchar(100) null
);
insert into pessoa (cpf, nome, data_Nascimento, cep, telefone) values (123, 'Maria', '1981-01-01', null, null);
insert into pessoa (cpf, nome, data_Nascimento, cep, telefone) values (456, 'Paulo', '1981-11-01', null, null);

create table funcionario
(
    cpf_funcionario int not null
        primary key,
    salario decimal(10,2) null,
    constraint funcionario_ibfk_1
        foreign key (cpf_funcionario) references pessoa (cpf)
            on update cascade
);
insert into funcionario (cpf_funcionario, salario) values (123, 15123.52);
insert into funcionario (cpf_funcionario, salario) values (456, 10456.74);

CREATE VIEW FuncionarioSalarioIdade AS
SELECT P.nome, F.salario, P.`data_Nascimento`, Cast(NOW() as date) as Hoje, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, P.`data_Nascimento`, NOW()) as idade
FROM funcionario F
INNER JOIN `pessoa` P
ON (F.`cpf_funcionario` = P.`cpf`);
```

**Consulta 1**:

```
Select * from FuncionarioSalarioIdade
```

**[Resultado](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c6e9b/1/0)**:

| nome | salario | data_Nascimento | Hoje | idade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Maria | 15123.52 | 1981-01-01 | 2021-07-16 | 40 |
| Paulo | 10456.74 | 1981-11-01 | 2021-07-16 | 39 |

**Coloquei o ano da data de nascimento de ambas as pessoas como nascidas em 1981 para evidenciar que o mês de nascimento e a data atual, hoje, estão sendo consideradas para a realização do cálculo.**